# Using optional backreferences to capture string optionally enclosed with quotes

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm trying to build a parser that would be able to extract the data using regex.

I want to be able to match

Here is what I have right now:

```
(\w+)\s+('|")([^\2\\]*(\\.[^\2\\]*)*)\2\s*;
```

The `([^\2\\]*(\\.[^\2\\]*)*)` part was taken from http://ad.hominem.org/log/2005/05/quoted_strings.php

Unfortunately I have two problems with this pattern.

First of all, I would like to be able to capture string which aren't enclosed with single/double quotes.

Having `print "hello world";` works but `print foobar;` doesnt't work. I haven't been able to make the backreference `\2` optional at the end.

Furthermore, I don't know if it's just the way I enclosed the regex, but I can't seem to be able to  parse multiple instance of this pattern.

If i try the regex with `print 'hello'; print 'foobar';`, it would just return the first `print 'hello';` part.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**Edit**

Here is a snippet of what I'm trying to parse:

```
listen          80;
server_name     domain.com *.domain.com;
rewrite ^       http://www.domain.com$request_uri? permanent;
```

I am trying to capture every action with their parameters. Basically I wan't to be able to parse the NGINX configuration file: http://wiki.nginx.org/FullExample

Comment: Is your goal to parse a PHP string?

Comment: This is a wild guess, but you can't you just change `('|")` to `('|"|)`?

Comment: @Jason: Nope, just trying to parse the nginx configuration file.

@ Frits: Yeah well it works. Dunno why but I'm sure I tried something similar earlier and it was failing.

Comment: well, what about something like `print "abc def";`? Does that still match as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A backreference [doesn't work](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) in a character class `[^\2]` like that. It might be a multi-character string, and cannot be used there. You could work around that using a `((?!\2).)*` construct. But it would really be simpler if you just simplified your match pattern.

The easiest approach here would be to list the three possible alternatives separately:

```
 /(\w+)\s+ (?: '([^']*)' |  "([^"]*)" | (\S+) ) \s*;/x
```

Obviously you would then have to fetch the results from the result sets [2], [3] or [4] manually.

Comment: That works great. Thanks! I don't really have too much experience with regex and it was my first time touching backreference.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match multiple times use `preg_match_all` instead. So long as the matching strings don't overlap you'll get all of them.